# Bool with json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, boolean

Hello I am trying to put the variable 'select' to fetch the bool value from a Json file I am not able to do anyone can help me (there is no code all I can get text but I can’t get bool). Thank you.

```
final _toDoController = TextEditingController();
  Map<String, dynamic> _toDoList = Map(); //change this.
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _readData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _toDoList = json.decode(data);
      });
    });
  }
  void _addToDo() {
    setState(() {
      Map<String, dynamic> newToDo = Map();
      newToDo['verificar'] = true;
      _toDoList.addAll(newToDo);
      _saveData();
    });
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool selected = _toDoList['verificar'];
    return Scaffold(
...
      ),
      body: Container(
color: selected ? Colors.green.withOpacity(0.90) : Colors.deepOrangeAccent.withOpacity(0.90),
...
),
    );
  }
  Future<File> _getFile() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return File("${directory.path}/data.json");
  }
  Future<File> _saveData() async {
    String data = json.encode(_toDoList);

    final file = await _getFile();
    return file.writeAsString(data);
  }
  Future<String> _readData() async {
    try {
      final file = await _getFile();

      return file.readAsString();
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }}}
```

Comment: provide sample json data

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean

Comment: the data variable in json.decode(data), what does it contain?

Comment: Future<File> _getFile() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return File("${directory.path}/data.json");
  }

  Future<File> _saveData() async {
    String data = json.encode(_toDoList);

    final file = await _getFile();
    return file.writeAsString(data);
  }

  Future<String> _readData() async {
    try {
      final file = await _getFile();

      return file.readAsString();
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the type of list you are using.

```
List _toDoList = []; //this returns an index based list. 

Map<String, dynamic> newTodo = Map(); //this list returns a list with a key and value pair
```

The solution is to either change `_toDoList` from index based `List` to a `Map`, or access the list using an `index`.

```
Map<String, dynamic> _toDoList = Map(); //change _toDoList to this
_toDoList.addAll(newToDo); //change to this
bool selected = _toDoList['verificar'] //this now works
```

or, with current code as it is, below works.

```
bool selected _toDoList[0]['verificar'];
```

**Hint:**
Print out the run type of a list or variable to see what it is, then it becomes easier to deal access it.

```
 print('a: ${_toDoList.runtimeType} : $_toDoList');
 print('b: ${_toDoList[0].runtimeType} : ${_toDoList[0]}');
 print('c: ${_toDoList[0]['verificar']}');

Map<String, dynamic> newToDo = Map();
newToDo['verificar'] = true;
Map<String, dynamic> _toDoList2 = Map();
_toDoList2.addAll(newToDo);

print('d: ${_toDoList2.runtimeType} : ${_toDoList2['verificar']}');
```

and see output, which tells you what type of list this is:

```
I/flutter (11261): a: List<dynamic> : [{verificar: true}]
I/flutter (11261): b: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> : {verificar: true}
I/flutter (11261): c: true
I/flutter (11261): d: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> : true
```

**In summary**, below works

```
Map<String, dynamic> _toDoList = Map(); //change this.

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _readData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _toDoList = json.decode(data);
      });
    });
  }

  void _addToDo() {
    setState(() {
      Map<String, dynamic> newToDo = Map();
      newToDo['verificar'] = true;
      _toDoList.addAll(newToDo);

      _saveData();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool selected = _toDoList[verificar];
```

Comment: hello I have expressed your code and gives me this error in emulator :
"
Failed assertion: Boolean Expression must not be null
See also:
https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors
"
can you continue to help me?(you want I send the code?)

Comment: what were the values of your print statements?